# Dijkstra's Algorithm with Turn Penalty Giving Sub-Optimal Path

Tags: dijkstra

I'm having a problem returning the optimal path from A to E using Dijkstra's algorithm with a turn penalty of 0.25 in the following figure:

[image: Graph]

My implementation returns path ABDE (since the shortest distance to D is calculated as 3.05 along the curve instead of 3.25 along the straight lines), which has total cost 1 + 0.25 + 1.8 + 0.25 + 1 = 4.3.

However, path ABCDE is the optimal path with total cost 1 + 1 + 0.25 + 1 + 1 = 4.25. How do I modify my implementation to account for this? Right now, all I'm doing is,
if d[u] + w(u, v) + 0.25 < d[v], then d[v] = d[u] + w(u, v) + 0.25.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm does not work with a turn penalty. If you want to use Dijkstra's algorithm, you will have to eliminate the turn penalty, for example by transforming the graph into a graph of original-node/arrival-direction pairs with edges and edge costs that incorporate the original problem's turn penalty.